# por algun motivo react dejo de leer modulos svg

Tags: reactjs

estoy trabajando en el mismo proyecto desde hace poco mas de un año y medio, el proyecto esta creado con la herramienta `create-react-app`, hoy estuve refactorizando en login y me encuentro con que react no esta importando un archivo `.svg`, en vscode me da el siguiente error: `No se encuentra el módulo "assets/aidyfa.svg" ni sus declaraciones de tipos correspondientes`, no estoy seguro de si es un problema de react o de alguna configuracion en mi vscode, dado que estuve utilizando varios plugins en vscode decidi restaurar por defecto la configuracion del archivo `setting.json`, pero me sigue dando el mismo error, la manera de mostrar el archivo es el siguiente:

```
import logo from "assets/aidyfa.svg";

<img className={classes.image} alt="AIDYFA" src={logo} />
```

este codigo funciono desde el principio, pero justamente hoy me encuentro con que react no encuentra el modulo, estuve investigando y puedo crear un `custom.d.ts` e incluirlo en mi tsconfig.json, pero decidi no hacerlo ya que `create-react-app` prepara el entorno de dessarollo por mi e incluye todo para poder trabajar sin configuraciones
, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Algún problema con la ruta relativa quizás? Prueba con "./assets/aidyfa.svg" o moviendo el archivo svg a la misma carpeta que el jsx.

Comment: Creo que la solución sería esa: importar el `svg` como una `img`. Fijate que eso es lo que proponen en esta pregunta [How to display svg icons(.svg files) in UI using React Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296499/how-to-display-svg-icons-svg-files-in-ui-using-react-component).